# add a timer to an effect dispatch in ngrx

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

I have the following effect

```
  addItem$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(SkusActions.addItemRequest),
      concatMap(({ payload, redirectTo }) =>
        this.dataService.addItem(payload).pipe(
          map(({ data }) =>
            data
              ? SkusActions.addItemSuccess(payload))
              : SkusActions.addItemFailure({})
          ),
          catchError((error) => of(SkusActions.addItemFailure(error)))
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

Since I am using graphql, I have to make sure that the query is succeeded or failed, (the query can go trought but have error in graphql so no data field)

Now, In the case of everything went trought correctly, I would like to add a timer of 3second BEFORE the `addItemSuccess` fire.

I tried

```
  addItem$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(SkusActions.addItemRequest),
      concatMap(({ payload, redirectTo }) =>
        this.dataService.addItem(payload).pipe(
          map(({ data }) =>
            data
              ? timer(3000).pipe(mapTo(SkusActions.addItemSuccess(payload)))
              : SkusActions.addItemFailure({})
          ),
          catchError((error) => of(SkusActions.addItemFailure(error)))
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

but it say the type do not match.

Answer (score -1):

`SkusActions.addItemFailure({})` returns an action (javascript object) while `timer(3000).pipe(...)` returns an Observable.

So you should use `switchMap` instead (or `concatMap` or `mergeMap` would work as well) and always return an Observable:

```
switchMap(({ data }) => data
  ? timer(3000).pipe(mapTo(SkusActions.addItemSuccess(payload)))
  : of(SkusActions.addItemFailure({}))
),
```

Comment: `switchMap` should not be the default suggestion. The OP could end up losing actions

Comment: That depends on what `addItem()` does, If this makes for example just an HTTP request then it doesn't matter.

Comment: That might be true in this case, but I don't think it should be the default - especially if people might not know the differences between them